# SQL Server Datetime to Datetime String Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datetime-format

I would like to update all of my `datetime` columns to a new string column that extracts the `date` portion only (which refers to `datetime` column type). I did some research, the format of the datestr should be:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @dt, 105) s2;
```

Seems like my query is not working:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[myTable]
SET [dbo].[myTable].datestr = (
   SELECT [dbo].[myTable].dt
   FROM [dbo].[myTable]
   WHERE [dbo].[myTable].ID = [dbo].[myTable].ID
)
```

[image]

Comment: Don't store dates as strings! You'll regret it....

Comment: This is for learning purposes to test out

Comment: Well the 'learniing' to take away is : "Don't store dates as strings! "

Comment: I don't see date-to-string conversion in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely getting an error similar to "sub query returned more than one row". The update query does not need a sub-query. It should be like so:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[myTable]
SET datestr = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dt, 105);
```

That being said, there is absolutely no need to store same information twice in a table. If you want your datetime in a specific format, format it on demand:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dt, 105) AS datestr
FROM [dbo].[myTable]
```